# Share an event between 2 forms usign a common class

Tags: vb.net

I would like to share an event to another form via a common class with a public shared event.

My code is setup like this:
Form1 is the main form where the button.click event is generated
Form2 is a subform displayed in Form1 in a panel control, where if the event is generated executes a sub.

To share data I use a commonData class, to share the only data i need, because I want to keep private function and variables in the single forms.

Can someone help me figure out what I'd like to do?

something like this, but working

```
Public Class commonData
  Public Shared Event event1()
End class

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click 
  RaiseEvent commonData.event1()
  End Sub
End class

Public Class Form2
  Private Sub eventFired(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles commonData.event1
  MsgBox("event")
  End Sub
End class
```

Comment: Can you show the code? _To share data I use a commonData class_ - provide no information

Comment: @Fabio the commonData class is a simple Public Class where I put a variabe to be shared between form1 and form2. I would like to use this method to share an event.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by sharing an event? What you actually trying to achieve by sharing an event?

Comment: @fabio I've added some code to make easier to understand what I'd like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many techniques to do that but this one **(which is one of those)** I hope might help you to have an idea how can have a shared Event between Forms or other classes.
First as you want here is the common module (you can use a class instead, is your choice; but `<Extension()>` go only in modules).

**CommonData as a Class and ExtensionUtils as a Module for extensions:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class CommonData

    Public Shared Event MyGlobalEvent(eventSender As Object, otherParams As String)
    Shared Sub RaiseMyGlobalEvent(eventSender As Object, otherParams As String)
        RaiseEvent MyGlobalEvent(eventSender, otherParams)
    End Sub

End Class

Module ExtensionUtils
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub ButtonClick(ByVal buttonCaller As Button, eventArgs As String)
        CommonData.RaiseMyGlobalEvent(buttonCaller, eventArgs)
    End Sub
End Module
```

And here the implementation:
***In this example I use a button named “Button1” in Form2 and when I click on it show a msgbox in Form1.***

**Form1:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.Show()

        AddHandler CommonData.MyGlobalEvent, Sub(objSender As Object, message As String)
                                                 MsgBox(message & vbCrLf & " But I'm telling you that from form " & Me.Name)
                                             End Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2:**

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Button1.Click, Sub()
                                      Button1.ButtonClick(("I'm clicked from form " & Me.Name))
                                  End Sub


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ty for the reply! if I'd like to stick with the class instead of the module, what does change?

Comment: If your event go to be a shared Event the better choice is using a module instead of a class (for me is more easy). But consider that as an alternative to your modus operandi. However you can call CommonData.RaiseMyGlobalEvent(buttonCaller, eventArgs) everywhere as is a shared Sub. And have a listener of MyGlobalEvent everywhere in your forms as is a shared Event. Have fun ;)

Comment: I've used only a part of the code to do what I wanted TY!

Comment: Don't forget to remove the event when the form closes.